# Convert to lowercase in group aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I want to return an aggregate of blog post tags and their total count. My blog posts are stored like so:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("532c323bb07ab5aace243c8e"),
    "title" : "Fitframe.js - Responsive iframes made easy",
    "tags" : [
        "JavaScript",
        "jQuery",
        "RWD"
    ]
}
```

I'm then executing the following pipeline:

```
printjson(db.posts.aggregate(
    { 
    $project: { 
      tags: 1,
      count: { $add: 1 } 
    } 
  }, 

  { 
    $unwind: '$tags' 
  },

  { 
    $group: { 
      _id: '$tags', 
      count: { 
        $sum: '$count' 
      },
      tags_lower: { $toLower: '$tags' }  
    }
  },

  { 
    $sort: { 
      _id: 1 
    } 
  }

));
```

So that the results are sorted correctly I need to sort on a lowercase version of each tag. However, when executing the above code I get the following error:

```
aggregate failed: {
    "errmsg" : "exception: unknown group operator '$toLower'",
    "code" : 15952,
    "ok" : 0
}
```

Do I need to do *another* projection to add the lowercase tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to add another projection ... you could fix it when you do the `$group`:

```
db.posts.aggregate(
    { 
    $project: { 
      tags: 1,
      count: { $add: 1 } 
    } 
  }, 

  { 
    $unwind: '$tags' 
  },

  { 
    $group: { 
      _id: {  tag: '$tags', lower: { $toLower : '$tags' } }, 
      count: { 
        $sum: '$count' 
      }

    }
  },

  { 
    $sort: { 
      "_id.lower": 1 
    } 
  }

)
```

In the above example, I've preserved the original name and added the lower case version to the `_id`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you must add it to the projection. It will not work in the group, only specific operators like `$sum` ( http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-group/ ) are counted as $group operators and capable of being used on that level of the group

Comment: `toLower` can be used in construction of the `_id` as shown in my answer though.

Comment: @WiredPrairie Indeed it can be used like that true, didn't think of that at the tme

Answer (score 2):

Add another projection step between `$unwind` and `$grop`:

```
...
{$project: {
  tags: {$toLower: '$tags'},
  count: 1
}}
...
```

And remove `tags_lower` from `$group`